# Handling Navigation in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have 2 pages in my Windows Phone 8.1 app.

The 1st page displays 9 image buttons. Its purpose is to allow the User to enter their 4 digit PIN to proceed to the next screen.

The 2nd page display other information.

I have an image button on my 2nd page that when pressed will take the User back to the 1st page.

If I press that button it will take me to 1st page.

If I then press the back button on my phone it will take me back to the 2nd page.

I had expected the app to exit?

What am i missing from my logic here?

thanks

Comment: Can you show the code how you Navigate to your 1st page? Do you use `Frame.GoBack()`? Have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: @Romasz most likely he's using Frame.Navigate(), which would explain the going back in "history".

Comment: @chaps. Sorry I have been away,  Yes, Ben, I am using Frame.Navigate.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele Yes, I just wanted to ensure with OP's code (which he should include in the question).

Comment: @Romasz, so sorry. jsut getting to speed with all this.  I will amend my question :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You can read more [about navigation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx), especially what happens when you *Navigate* and about method *Frame.GoBack()*.

Comment: HI, useful link - thanks.  So, brief synopsis is that I use: Frame.Navigate(typeof(mypagename))  and the windows button uses GoBack.  So should I override the back button in Windows as I read that is bad practice to do so?  Thanks